# Request permission for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION

Tags: nativescript

I want to use [ActivityRecognition](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) in NativeScript. So for that, I need `com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` permission.

For the newer versions of Android, I also need to request the permission from code in addition to the manifest. In NativeScript, I plan to do that using [nativescript-permissions](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions) plugin with the following code:

```
permissions.requestPermission(com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, "I need these permissions because reasons")
.then(function() {
    // ...
});
```

But this code trows error: `Cannot read property ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION of undefined`.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"\>` to your manifest and executed a full `build` of your app? Also if this permission isn't considered "dangerous" by Google then you don't need to request the permission at runtime, it only needs to be in your manifest. Also, have you performed the setup for adding google play services? https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup If you haven't then it will always be undefined because you don't have the sdk in your application :)

Comment: Are you using TypeScript!? If so you will need either to add the definitions or to cast com to any (`declare var com:any`).. another possible solution for nativescript-permissions is to pass the permission as a string e.g. `permissions.requestPermission("com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION", //mode code follows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_REC‌​OGNITION"/>` to your manifest and executed a full build of your app? If this permission isn't considered "dangerous" by Google then you don't need to request the permission at runtime, it only needs to be in your manifest.

Also, have you performed the [setup for adding google play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)? If you haven't then it will always be undefined because you don't have the sdk in your application :)

**Additional Update**: As of Android 10 (Q / 29), you need to ask for this permission at runtime, so make sure you take that into account. In addition, you need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />` to your manifest to cover 29 and that runtime use case.